# Vim fill command line with currently highlighted word in substitution

Tags: neovim, command-line, substitute

I have `incsearch` on, so when I type `:s/thingS` it will highlight the `thingS` part of `thingSoFar` in the below text

```
see, this thing is the thingSoFar thing
```

When I am typing that command line with my cursor at the first column, first the `t`, then `th`, then `thi` of "this" are highlighted. When I type the `n`, it no longer matches `this`, so the highlighting jumps to the first `thing`'s `thin`. When I type `g` the highlighting remains on that word. Then when I type `S` it jumps forwards to highlight the `thingS` of `thingSoFar`. Standard `incsearch` behaviour.

Now, I would like to `<C-r><C-w>` the *currently highlighted* word, rather than the word that my cursor was on when I entered command line mode.

E.g., I put my cursor on the first column in the line above (on the `s` of see)

Now I type

```
:s/thingS<C-r><C-w>
```

I would *like* my command line to be filled like this:

```
:s/thingSoFar
```

instead I get this

```
:s/thingSsee
```

How can I actually get the result I want? How can I complete the word I'm typing in the command line with the currently incsearch-highlighted word?

Answer (score 3):

There is `:help c_ctrl-l`, which inserts one character of the first match:

```
:s/thingS
:s/thingSo       " <C-l>
:s/thingSoF      " <C-l>
:s/thingSoFa     " <C-l>
:s/thingSoFar    " <C-l>
```

but a) the characters come from the first match, which is probably not that useful, and b) it only inserts one character, which possibly means doing lots of `<C-l>`s to get what you want. In this case, pressing `<C-l>` four times is not a lot worse than pressing `<C-r><C-w>` once but still.

At a much higher level, you have [the venerable CmdlineComplete plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2222).

Answer (score 2):

running `vim -u NONE` and activating `set incsearch` does result in your desired behaviour.

`<C-R><C-W>` does fill in the entire word `thingSoFar`.
Within substitution and search on the cmdline.

I am not able to provide you a specific patch from the repository which implements this functionality but it is documented since this commit to be the default behaviour for `incsearch`: [Version 7.0226](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/d3667a2e2971a879194084f4b61b8ff7ff9765a2#diff-4188ca60fe651289f55943772fd6b6b867e721976d75f8be575ecb98ad30e4cbR176-R178)

Comment: You're right, that works for me too. My main editor is actually neovim, hadn't thought to check this sorry about that.